# Mean value of taken unique cards' number

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The player takes cards from the deck with return. There are N cards and K attempts. K can be more or less than N. Probabilities to be taken for each card is equal. What is the mean amount of unique taken cards after K attempts of player?

I tried to solve this task by the next way:

The probability to take $K - i$ unique cards from the deck is

$\frac{C_N^{K-i} (K - i)^i}{N^k}$

because there are $N^K$ ways to do $K$ choices and we can take $(K - i)$ different cards from deck by $C_N^{K - i}$ ways. Other $i$ choices can be only about cards that have been already chosen. It is $(K - i)^i$ ways.

In this way mean value is:

$M = \sum_{i=0}^{K - 1} \frac{C_N^{K-i} (K - i)^i}{N^k} (K - i)$

It is not right answer and it is not appropriate for the case when K > N. I have a suspicion that this task can be solved with multinomial distribution, but I can not understand how exactly I should do it.

Comment: Each card has a unique value?  If so:  The expected number of singletons can be computed via indicator variables.  The probability that you get value $i$ exactly once is $K\times \frac 1N\times \left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^{K-1}$.  As there are $N$ possible values, when we sum we just get $K\times  \left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^{K-1}$

Comment: Note:  the posted solution, from @MarkoRiedel, is answering a different question than I was answering.  I was computing the expected number of singletons (values that are drawn exactly once), while he computed the expected number of values that are drawn at least once.  It's easy to do the latter by indicator variables as well, I'll post a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classifying according to  the number $q$ of different  unique cards we
obtain  from  first  principles   for  the  number  of  configurations
(i.e.  number of  sequences of  draws  with replacement  from the  $N$
cards)

$${N\choose q} {K\brace q} q!$$

Let us verify that this sums to $N^K:$

$$\sum_{q=1}^N {N\choose q} {K\brace q} q!
= K! [z^K] \sum_{q=1}^N {N\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q.$$

We may add in $q=0$ as it does not contribute when $K\ge 1:$

$$K! [z^K] \sum_{q=0}^N {N\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q
= K! [z^K] \exp(Nz) = N^K.$$

The sanity check  goes through. Now for the expected  number of unique
cards we get

$$K! [z^K] \sum_{q=1}^N q {N\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^q
= K! N [z^K] \sum_{q=1}^N  {N-1\choose q-1} (\exp(z)-1)^q
\\ = K! N [z^K] (\exp(z)-1)
\sum_{q=1}^N  {N-1\choose q-1} (\exp(z)-1)^{q-1}
\\ = K! N [z^K] (\exp(z)-1)
\sum_{q=0}^{N-1}  {N-1\choose q} (\exp(z)-1)^{q}
\\ = K! N [z^K] (\exp(z)-1) \exp((N-1)z)
= K! N [z^K] (\exp(Nz)-\exp((N-1)z))
\\ = N \times (N^K - (N-1)^K).$$

Divide by $N^K$ for the expectation

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
N\times \left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^K\right).}$$

**Addendum.** We  can also  answer the question  of what  the expected
number of singletons is. This is the species

$$\mathfrak{S}_{=N}
(\mathfrak{P}_{=0}(\mathcal{Z})
+\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{P}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+\mathfrak{P}_{\ge 2}(\mathcal{Z})).$$

which yields the generating function

$$G(z, u) = (\exp(z)-z+uz)^N.$$

We get as a sanity check

$$K! [z^K] G(z, 1) = K! [z^K] \exp(Nz) =N^K$$

which is correct and the check goes through.

We obtain for the expectation

$$K! [z^K] \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial u} G(z, u)\right|_{u=1}
\\ = K! [z^K] \left. N (\exp(z)-z+uz)^{N-1} z \right|_{u=1}
\\ = K! N [z^{K-1}] \exp((N-1)z)
= K N (N-1)^{K-1}.$$

Divide by $N^K$ for the expectation

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
K\times \left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{K-1}.}$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is "what is the expected number of values that are drawn at least once" we can answer via indicator variables, using linearity of expectation.

The probability that a given answer is observed is $$1-\left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^K$$  Summing over the $N$ possible values gives the expectation $$\boxed {N\times \left( 1-\left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^K\right)}$$